# Wget only downloads files from first directory and from all other susequent directories, it just downloads index.html files

Tags: wget

I am trying to download whole website including everything, pictures, zips, pdfs, everything. Wget works fine for downloading files in immediate folder but for all sub-folders, it just downloads a index.html - which contains all the file names in sub-folder. How can I download all the files.

Comment: What is the exact command you've used? As in what options did you specify?

Comment: I used --no-check-certificate under HTTPS option, --recursive under recursive retrieval and --no-parent. I am using VisualWget. And problem is only with sub-folder, not with folders